# Plot barchart of number of unique values in each Pandas group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to make a bar chart with Matplotlib or Seaborn that will represent number of unique values of each month:

```
import pandas as pd

date_list = ['jan', 'jan', 'jan', 'jan', 'feb', 'feb', 'feb', 'feb', 'mar', 'mar', 'mar', 'mar']
value_list = ['high', 'high', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'high']

print(len(date_list))
print(len(value_list))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_list,
                  'value': value_list})
                  
print(df)

    date   value
0   jan    high
1   jan    high
2   jan    high
3   jan    high
4   feb  medium
5   feb    high
6   feb     low
7   feb     low
8   mar     low
9   mar     low
10  mar     low
11  mar    high



Unique values:

jan: 1
feb: 3
mar: 2
```

Graph should be ordered by months.

I know that I can do :

```
sns.countplot(x = 'date', hue = 'value', data = df)
```

But this gives me count of every category in value_list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
s = df.groupby('date', sort=False)['value'].nunique()

s.plot.bar()
```

[image: img]

Or remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with both columns and also remove `hue` parameter:

```
sns.countplot(x = 'date', data = df.drop_duplicates(['date','value']))
```

[image: img]

EDIT: Solution for plot multiple DataFrames in same x-axis:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_list[:5],
                  'value': value_list[:5]})
                  
print(df2)

dfs = [df1, df2]

df = (pd.concat(dfs, keys=range(len(dfs))).rename_axis(('no', 'i'))
        .reset_index()
        .drop_duplicates(['no', 'date','value'])_

print (df)
    no   i date   value
0    0   0  jan    high
4    0   4  feb  medium
5    0   5  feb    high
6    0   6  feb     low
8    0   8  mar     low
11   0  11  mar    high
12   1   0  jan    high
16   1   4  feb  medium

# df1.plot.bar(x='date', y='count nunique')
sns.countplot(x = 'date', hue = 'no', data = df)
```

Comment: It works good, but when I use my full dataset, months on X-axis are all over the place

Comment: @taga - hmmm, both solutions failed? What means `months on X-axis are all over the place` ? Is possible see picture?

Comment: They are not ordered, i have a dataset with around 400 rows, 12 different months, but when I plot it, its not January->February etc.

Comment: @taga - Is possible sorted dates first?

Comment: @taga I guess you need to [reindex the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71111601/16343464)

Comment: Probably, your months is a string, so python sort it in alphabet order. Try to change it to datetime type - month format

Comment: I have used countploat with ORDER parameter. Thanks !
Is there a way to change a code a little bit so that I can plot multiple datasets on the same graphs with bars next to each other?

Comment: @taga - Can you be more specific? There is list of DataFrames?

Comment: well imagine that i have df1 and df2 instead of df. Column names are the same, but values are different. 
I want to represent both dataframes (months on x-axis) but data for df1 should be in red, data for df2 should be in blue.
So I do not think of 2 figures next to each other, I think one figure (one graph) with values from both dataframes

Comment: @taga - answer was EDITed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compute first the groups yourself. Then feed to [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) instead of `countplot`:

```
df2 = (df.groupby('date', sort=False)
         .agg(**{'unique values': ('value', 'nunique')})
         .reset_index()
      )

#   date  unique values
# 0  jan              1
# 1  feb              3
# 2  mar              2


sns.barplot(data=df2, x='date', y='unique values')
```

output:

[image]

##### Ensuring order of the months (and presence of all):

```
from calendar import month_abbr  # use month_name for full names

# or use a hand defined list
order = [m.lower()for m in month_abbr][1:]
# ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']

df2 = (df.groupby('date', sort=False)
         .agg(**{'unique values': ('value', 'nunique')})
         .reindex(order)
         .reset_index()
      )
sns.barplot(data=df2, x='date', y='unique values')
```

output:

[image]